# WinUI 3 xaml how to pass Mouse position as command parameter

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, winui-3, winui

I would like to pass the mouse position as a commandparameter to my command that is executed on clicking a MenuFlyoutItem. Does anyone know how to do this? I would like to have the new item added to the 'Views' collection appear at the mouse position at the canvas. I know I can accomplish it in code-behind, but would like not to.

```
<controls1:CanvasView.ContextFlyout>
    <MenuFlyout>
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Add view" Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.AddViewCommand}" CommandParameter="{What to put here??}" />
    </MenuFlyout>
</controls1:CanvasView.ContextFlyout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you will need to keep track of the mouse position.

For example:

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [RelayCommand]
    private void AddView(Point point)
    {
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
[ObservableObject]
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private Point _mousePosition;

    private void RootGrid_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PointerPoint point = e.GetCurrentPoint(this.RootGrid);
        MousePosition = point.Position;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new();
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="MousePositionExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:MousePositionExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid
        x:Name="RootGrid"
        Background="Transparent"
        PointerMoved="RootGrid_PointerMoved">
        <Canvas Background="Transparent">
            <Canvas.ContextFlyout>
                <MenuFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem
                        Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.AddViewCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{x:Bind MousePosition, Mode=OneWay}"
                        Text="Add view" />
                </MenuFlyout>
            </Canvas.ContextFlyout>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

**Note**

I'm using the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty) NuGet package for the MVVM design.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I was hoping there would be a way to do this with just XAML.